# .Net Application Has No Icon in Windows 10 Unless Pinned

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, icons, windows-10

I developed my application in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. It appears fine in Windows 8. However, upon testing it in Windows 10, there is only a blank space:

[image]

You can interact with the task bar item as normal, but the icon does not show. However if you pin it to the taskbar, then the icon is displayed. Is there a way to fix this? Why is this happening?

Comment: Why the down vote? There are no results on google for this question.

Comment: This question is endlessly easier to answer when you post a link to the icon or assembly you are using.  Google "windows 10 reset shell icon cache" to try something.

Comment: It's with any .Net application I create. The icon will not display, even if that application is a blank form.

Comment: Also, I am setting the icon through the application properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted the Windows 10 device, and rebuilt my project, and it appears to be working fine now. Someone also suggested resetting the shell icon cache, but restarting worked for me before I got to that step.